# Knockout observable array - prevent scroll to top when updated

Tags: knockout.js

I have problem with scrolling when adding items to observable array. After data are pushed to collection, page scrolls to top.

```
function LoadEntries(take, skip) {  
  vm.entries.push({...})
};
```

I found similar problem on one gist, so I used it as example:
https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/qYBVre

Just click on "Read More Entries" and it scrolls to start of page.

Why it happens and how to prevent this?

I want to keep position when reloaded data. Just as it will be for example in Asp.Net on UpdatePanel.

Comment: I can't reproduce scrolling issue in your [codepen](https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/qYBVre). But the issue occurs on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/devghost/2988758) because he is using `href="#"`, that will move the scroll to the top.

Comment: Yes, that's why I changed it to button. But as Jason pointed it is because of DOM recreate. Array and DOM is removed then recreated. So it jumps.

Answer (score 1):

With the example at https://codepen.io/raptor/pen/qYBVre the reason the page scrolls back to the top is that the click event is removing all the elements before re-adding some back in. Knockout updates the DOM between the remove and the add so there is a brief moment where the entire length of the document is only the header portion, and scrolling is forced to reset.

There's probably lots of options for getting around that, but here's two:

**1.** Don't remove the existing items when updating your list. Just add/remove/update the affected ones. Any adding and removing will of course change the size of the screen so the scroll position will still change depending on how many you're adding/removing at a time and where your scroll position is in relation to the bottom of the screen.

**2.** Don't tell knockout about the changes until you've finished refilling the array.

```
//vm.entries.removeAll();
vm.entries().length = 0; //remove elements from the underlying array without triggering overvable notifications
LoadEntries(pageSize, ++page * pageSize);
```

Changing the underlying array instead of the observable array bypasses knockout's change triggers. The only update happens when the entries are loaded back in with `vm.entries.push(...)`. In more complex scenarios you may need to tell knockout manually that a change has been made to an underlying array with `vm.entries.valueHasMutated();`

Comment: Well, nice idea. It works in my example. But when I tried it in out real application, nothing changes. Still jumps. I understand problem with DOM recreating. And I can't just update items in array. After refresh everything should change, so it is better to reload all.

Comment: @Raptor Can you create a reproduction using parts of your own code?